# How to Execute DOS commands through maven?

Tags: node.js, maven, build, dos, gruntjs

I got solution for `ant` but how can I execute DOS command through `maven` ?
I am building my script in `gruntjs` and for run that I use node command prompt but I want to execute that command through maven. Any Idea???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a use case for [Maven's Exec Plugin](http://mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/).

Experiment with `exec:exec` goal in the plugin.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>Script Run</id>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <executable>${basedir}/<relativepathinyourproject>/yourscript.bat</executable>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but .bat files are created only in windows, I am creating application for windows as well as Mac, so is there is any solution for mac ?

Comment: maven profiles might be the right way to manage such scenario. Instead you can also use a java program to wrap over bat and sh files :).